# Bootstrap div clear fix

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

hi i have 3 div and i want div "aaaa" up . but i cant this. i use clearfix did'nt working my code ;

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3 br">s</div>
       <div class="clearfix"> </div>
       <div class="col-md-3 br">s</div>
       <div class="col-md-9 br" style="height:700px">aaa</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my image ;
[image]

Comment: Off topic: English is not your mother language!

Comment: im sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Hope it works

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 br">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">s</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">s</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9 br" style="height:700px">aaa</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      
      <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid #f00;">
        <div>s</div>
        <div>s</div>
      </div>
       
      <div>
        <div>aaa</div>
      </div>       
      
    </div>
</div>
```